# JSF rich:datatable column display very long text in multiple lines

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, richdatatable

I have a richdatatable in jsf .xhtml page  . I have a very long text for a particular cell.
How can i set the width of the column and also display the text within the specified cell.
I am new to JSF and CSS. I am providing an example. Suppose I have two columns in a richdatatable and one of them have a very long text. I want that very long text to get displayed in lines(wrap text) rather than in a single line.  I m not sure where, how and what to put as part of CSS

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewFileTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form>
            <rich:dataTable value="#{fileController.feedbackFileItems}" var="item" id="table">
                    <rich:column>
                       <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFeedbackTitle_feedbackPK_feedbackId}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.feedbackPK.feedbackId}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFeedbackTitle_department}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.department}"/>
                    </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
            </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Could you please try demonstrating with relevant example(s) - [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Apologies for not providing the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **displaying** long text in multiple line you can use `width` attribute of `rich:column`:

```
<rich:column width="150" ...>
```

or the same for `h:column`:

```
<h:column width="110">
```

---

If you **don't want to display** text of datatable cell in multiple lines, then 
1) you can use `columnClasses` attribute of `rich:dataTable` and specify no-wrap style for that column. For example combination

```
<rich:dataTable columnClasses="nowrap,">
```

with CSS

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

will be resulted as table with non wrapped first column.

2) You can use `style` or `styleClass` attributes of `rich:column` for the same result (with the same CSS).